# Rails booleans bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rather misterious problem dealing with booleans in Rails, here is how to reproduce:

1. rails new boolean_bug
2. rails generate model User verified:boolean

With this you should have an empty project with the User model.

3 Inside boolean_bug/app/models/user.rb

'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save :set_false
 attr_accessible :verified                 

 private  
   def set_false  
     self.verified = false
   end
end
```

4 In the console know reproduce:

```
$rails -v 
Rails 3.0.1

$ rails console --sandbox
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > User.create!
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
from /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:56:in `save!'
from /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:in `save!'
from /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!
```

5 Change `self.verified = false` to `self.verified = 0`

6 Go to the console again

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > User.create!
 => #<User id: 1, verified: false, created_at: "2010-10-31 04:23:13", updated_at: "2010-10-31 04:23:13">
```

So the point is that saving using false does not work, but true, 1, 0 do work, is this a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry not a rails bug, its actually because the before_filter returns false from the assignment, thus active record won't save.

Comment: I'm a beginner to Ruby on Rails, and this answer saved my life! Thank you!